# Bash if statement with multiple variables

Tags: bash, if-statement

Hello I am trying to make a simple bash script and am very new to it.

With the the if statement I am trying to count up like a clock.

So the output would be for example 16:59:58, 16:59:59, 17:00:00

The seconds and minutes work, however the first if statement is not working.

When it gets to 23:59:59, it is meant to go to 00:00:00 however it goes to 24:60:00

Any help?

```
if [[ "$hours" -eq 23 && "$minutes" -eq 60 && "$seconds" -eq 60 ]]
then
    seconds=0
    minutes=0
    hours=0
    ((date++))
else
    if [[ "$minutes" -eq 60 ]]
    then
        minutes=00
        ((hours++))
    else
        if [[ "$seconds" -eq 60 ]]
        then
            seconds=00
            ((minutes++))
        fi
    fi
fi
```

Comment: What's `date`? How are you actually incrementing `seconds`?

Comment: There's also an `elif` clause available, so that you don't have to nest `if` statements like this.

Comment: Cool trick, you can write scripts inside `((` and if's with `? :` ternary operator. `(( hours == 23 && minutes == 60 && seconds == 60 && ( seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0, date++ ) ))`. `to 23:59:59` - then you should compare with `59` not with `60`.

Comment: `"$hours" -eq 23` should be `"$hours" -eq 24`. You're testing the value *after* it has been incremented.

Comment: The way you've written it, it will go from `22:59:59` to `0:0:0`.

Comment: @chepner seconds is just a +=1. date is just a number. I am not interested in actually keeping time.I am making fake log data.

Comment: @Barmar I know, it doesn't have to be 100% accurate as I am only making fake log data. But if you know how to make it 00, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work from the lowest order field up, instead of testing all the variables.

```
((seconds++))
if [[ $seconds -eq 60 ]]
then 
    seconds=0
    ((minutes++))
fi
if [[ $minutes -eq 60 ]]
then
    minutes=0
    ((hours++))
fi
if [[ $hours -eq 24 ]]
then
    hours=0
    ((date++))
fi
```